# Battleships: one input loop too many

Tags: java

I am making a small battleships game. When I run the game and simulate the user winning it asks for 1 more set of coordinates even though the user has won. After entering in one more set of coordinates the game then says you have won.

I can't seem to pinpoint the problem can anyone help?

Thanks,

Here is my code

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Battleships {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("You'll have 10 tries to destroy the ship");

    String[][] displayGrid = { 
            { "O", "O", "O", "O", "O" }, 
            { "O", "O", "O", "O", "O" },
            { "O", "O", "O", "O", "O" }, 
            { "O", "O", "O", "O", "O" }, 
            { "O", "O", "O", "O", "O" } 
            };

    String[][] internalGrid = {
            { "O", "O", "O", "O", "O" },
            { "O", "O", "O", "O", "O" },
            { "O", "O", "O", "O", "O" },
            { "O", "O", "O", "O", "O" }, 
            { "O", "O", "O", "O", "O" } 
            };

    Random dice1 = new Random();
    int r = 0;
    r = dice1.nextInt(4);

    Random dice2 = new Random();
    int c = 0;
    c = dice2.nextInt(5);

    // Generates location of 2x1 ship

    internalGrid[r][c] = "X";
    internalGrid[r + 1][c] = "X";
    // inserts random location into internal grid

    for (int row = 0; row < displayGrid.length; row++) {

        for (int col = 0; col < displayGrid[row].length; col++) {
            System.out.print(displayGrid[row][col] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();
    int ucol = 0;
    int urow = 0;
    int hits = 0;

    for (int row = 0; row < internalGrid.length; row++) {

        for (int col = 0; col < internalGrid[row].length; col++) {
            System.out.print(internalGrid[row][col] + "\t"); 
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
     //print internal grid for debugging

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        do {
            Scanner row1 = new Scanner(System.in);  
            System.out.println("Enter a row between 1 and 5");
            urow = row1.nextInt() - 1;
        }

        while (urow > 4 || urow < 0);

        do {
            Scanner col1 = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter a column between 1 and 5");
            ucol = col1.nextInt() - 1;
        }

        while (ucol > 4 || ucol < 0);


        if (internalGrid[r][c] == "H" && internalGrid[r + 1][c] == "H" ) {
            System.out.println("You win!!");
            i= 10;} //i think the issue is here??
        else if (internalGrid[urow][ucol] == "X") {
            System.out.println("Hit!!");
            internalGrid[urow][ucol] = "H";
        }
        else if (internalGrid[urow][ucol] == "H") {
            System.out.println("You already hit that location");} 
        else {
            System.out.println("Miss :(");

        }
    }

    System.out.println("Game Finished!!");

}

}
```

Comment: I've commented the same until I noted that it is from the DO command above. @CoderinoJavarino

Comment: @JorgeCampos Sorry i don't really understand could you explain what you mean?

Comment: There were another user comment that was saying that your while code does nothing, but we realize that it belongs to the `do` code above it since it is not well formatted it is not clear at first sight.

Comment: You could describe what output do you expect, and what are you actually recieving?

Comment: @JorgeCampos oh ok i think the problem is that the for loop is not broken after winning. how can i break it

Comment: add a `break` command after the output of "you win"

Comment: What is this supposed to do?  `while (urow > 4 || urow < 0);`   ....is an infinite loop....

Comment: Oh wait, I see, it belongs with the corresponding do loop above.  You could improve on your coding style a bit. :)

Comment: @JorgeCampos i tried that but it only breaks the if loop

Comment: @selbie i know :( , is there anyway to fix this without rewriting a good chunk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect it has something to do with this line right here:

```
    if (internalGrid[r][c] == "H" && internalGrid[r + 1][c] == "H" ) {
```

I think you meant to use `urow` and `ucol` instead of `r` and `c` ???

Take all this out:

```
    if (internalGrid[r][c] == "H" && internalGrid[r + 1][c] == "H" ) {
        System.out.println("You win!!");
        i= 10;} //i think the issue is here??
    else if (internalGrid[urow][ucol] == "X") {
        System.out.println("Hit!!");
        internalGrid[urow][ucol] = "H";
    }
    else if (internalGrid[urow][ucol] == "H") {
        System.out.println("You already hit that location");} 
    else {
        System.out.println("Miss :(");

    }
```

And replace with this:

```
boolean isAlreadyHit = (internalGrid[urow][ucol] == 'H');
boolean isNewHit = (internalGrid[urow][ucol] == 'X');

if (isAlreadyHit) {
    System.out.println("You already hit that location");} 
}
else if (isNewHit) {
    System.out.println("Hit!");
    internalGrid[urow][ucol] = 'H';
} 
else {
    System.out.println("Miss!");
}

boolean isWinner = true;
for (int row = 0; row < internalGrid.length; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < internalGrid[row].length; col++) {
        if (internalGrid[row][col] == 'X') {
            isWinner = false;
        }
    }
}

if (isWinner) {
     System.out.println("You win!");
     break;  // breaks out of the outer for loop
}
```

Comment: ah thanks that works, i'll sit down now and figure out how exactly it worked and why mine did not thanks

Comment: If you like the answer, you should at least upvote it.  If it works for you, you should give it the green check box (accept the answer).

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this site, I didn't know you could check it.  I up voted it after you posted but it says that it won't be publicly displayed because by reputation needs to be higher than 15